# Google Ads - Billing transactions don't match campaign amount spent

Tags: google, google-ads, google-search-ads-360

I have a client who has spent $3,000.00 on Google Ads within the last 6 months. Or at least this is what the campaign is saying within google ads. We have hit the 3,000 dollar spend and have paused the campaign.

when I go the billing side of things (tools/setup/billing & payments) for google Ads for this campaign it says I have only spent around 1,250.00 for the 6 months with the last bill being on novermber 6 2018. Without asking my client, how much was my client actually charged for the 6th months? Will there be a 1000$ charge coming out of nowhere? Did google remove invalid clicks? why is our campaign data double what the actual billing transactions are?

Comment: After consulting with Google, they don't even have an answer for me. The billing was around 2900 which was another random number they threw in the mix. The report still doesn't equal up to 3k. But Google said you can rely on the google ads interface